# Prolog how to swap two by two elements in a list function?

Tags: list, prolog, swap

I need a function in Prolog: `swapcouple(L, L1)`.

`swapcouple([a,b,c,d,e], M)` --> output `M=[b,a,d,c,e]`

`swapcouple([a,b,c,d], M)` --> output `M=[b,a,d,c]`

Answer (score 2):

(what have you tried?) This is a valid definition:

```
swapcouple([a,b,c,d,e], M) :- M=[b,a,d,c,e].    
swapcouple([a,b,c,d], M) :- M=[b,a,d,c].
```

Proceed by abstraction. For example,

```
swapcouple([A,B,C,D,E], M) :- M=[B,A,D,C,E].    
swapcouple([A,B,C,D], M) :- M=[B,A,D,C].
```

Do you see where I'm going? `[A,B,C,D,E] = [A,B | R]` where `R = [C,D,E]`. Can we use that?

```
swapcouple([A,B|R], M) :- R=[C,D,E], M=[B,A|S], S=[D,C,E].
```

Right? Here's the crucial bit. `R=[C,D,E], S=[D,C,E]` is the same as `swapcouple(R,S)`, isn't it?

```
swapcouple([A,B|R], M) :- M=[B,A|S], swapcouple(R,S).
```

*Assuming* that `swapcouple` does what it is advertised to do, we *can just use it* when the need arises. Here you've got your very own [*recursive*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) procedure (well, predicate). It is even [*tail recursive modulo cons*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons), which is even more hip and fun.

Few more edge cases are missing there. I'm positive you can finish it up.

Comment: Looks great, but I would probably write `swapcouple([A,B|R], [B,A|S]) :- swapcouple(R, S).` because I'm fancy like that.

Comment: @DanielLyons small steps! small steps! :)

Answer (score 1):

The implementation can hardly get more direct than this:

```
list_swappedcouples([],[]).
list_swappedcouples([A],[A]).
list_swappedcouples([A,B|Xs],[B,A|Ys]) :-
   list_swappedcouples(Xs,Ys).
```

Here are your sample queries:

```
?- list_swappedcouples([a,b,c,d,e],Ls).
Ls = [b,a,d,c,e] ;                        % succeeds, but leaves behind choicepoint
false.

?- list_swappedcouples([a,b,c,d],Ls).
Ls = [b,a,d,c].                           % succeeds deterministically
```

---

#### Edit 2015-06-03

We can utilize first argument indexing to improve determinism.

```
list_with_swapped_couples([],[]).
list_with_swapped_couples([X|Xs],Ys) :-
   list_prev_w_swapped_couples(Xs,X,Ys).

list_prev_w_swapped_couples([],X,[X]).
list_prev_w_swapped_couples([X1|Xs],X0,[X1,X0|Ys]) :-
   list_with_swapped_couples(Xs,Ys).
```

Note that all following sample queries succeed deterministically.

```
?- list_with_swapped_couples([],Xs).
Xs = [].

?- list_with_swapped_couples([1],Xs).
Xs = [1].

?- list_with_swapped_couples([1,2],Xs).
Xs = [2,1].

?- list_with_swapped_couples([1,2,3],Xs).
Xs = [2,1,3].

?- list_with_swapped_couples([1,2,3,4],Xs).
Xs = [2,1,4,3].

?- list_with_swapped_couples([1,2,3,4,5],Xs).
Xs = [2,1,4,3,5].
```